# How to access URL in virtual machine from browser in host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, virtualbox

I'm running a kubernetes cluster inside a virtual machine.
I can access(curl) the URL https://wso2-apim/carbon from the virtual machine which is set up using a kubernetes ingress to point to a service running in the cluster.

However, I need to view it in a browser. First I tried to get it done by installing a text-only web browser such as lynx in the virtual machine but I can't do my requirement since it doesn't have javascript.

So I'm checking on how to access that URL from the browser in my host machine. (Mac)
Can you please guide me how to get it done?

```
pasan@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get ing --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                          HOSTS               ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
vick-system   gw-ingress                                    wso2-apim-gateway   10.0.2.15   80, 443   16h
vick-system   pub-store-ingress                             wso2-apim           10.0.2.15   80, 443   16h
vick-system   vick-observability-portal-dashboard-ingress   vick-dashboard      10.0.2.15   80        16h
```

Ingress setup for the service I'm trying to access:

```
pasan@ubuntu:~$ kubectl describe ing pub-store-ingress -n vick-system
Name:             pub-store-ingress
Namespace:        vick-system
Address:          10.0.2.15
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  SNI routes wso2-apim
Rules:
  Host       Path  Backends
  ----       ----  --------
  wso2-apim
             /   gateway:9443 (<none>)
Annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name:   route
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough:       true
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:          false
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity":"cookie","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash":"sha1","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name":"route","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough":"true"},"name":"pub-store-ingress","namespace":"vick-system"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"wso2-apim","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"gateway","servicePort":9443},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["wso2-apim"]}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                      nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity:             cookie
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash:  sha1
Events:                                             <none>
```

List of services:

```
pasan@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                                                   AGE
default         kubernetes                              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                                                                                                                   16h
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend                    ClusterIP      10.102.146.126   <none>        80/TCP                                                                                                                    16h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                           NodePort       10.102.166.109   10.0.2.15     80:31139/TCP,443:32537/TCP                                                                                                16h
istio-system    grafana                                 ClusterIP      10.97.173.253    <none>        3000/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
istio-system    istio-citadel                           ClusterIP      10.96.221.235    <none>        8060/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                                         16h
istio-system    istio-egressgateway                     ClusterIP      10.98.223.83     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                                                                                                            16h
istio-system    istio-galley                            ClusterIP      10.101.43.78     <none>        443/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                                          16h
istio-system    istio-ingressgateway                    LoadBalancer   10.105.4.150     <pending>     80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:32425/TCP,8060:31612/TCP,853:30264/TCP,15030:31349/TCP,15031:30408/TCP   16h
istio-system    istio-pilot                             ClusterIP      10.102.142.98    <none>        15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                     16h
istio-system    istio-policy                            ClusterIP      10.98.119.8      <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP                                                                                               16h
istio-system    istio-sidecar-injector                  ClusterIP      10.110.150.219   <none>        443/TCP                                                                                                                   16h
istio-system    istio-statsd-prom-bridge                ClusterIP      10.98.218.30     <none>        9102/TCP,9125/UDP                                                                                                         16h
istio-system    istio-telemetry                         ClusterIP      10.109.56.176    <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                     16h
istio-system    jaeger-agent                            ClusterIP      None             <none>        5775/UDP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP                                                                                                16h
istio-system    jaeger-collector                        ClusterIP      10.107.248.128   <none>        14267/TCP,14268/TCP                                                                                                       16h
istio-system    jaeger-query                            ClusterIP      10.97.91.158     <none>        16686/TCP                                                                                                                 16h
istio-system    prometheus                              ClusterIP      10.98.16.190     <none>        9090/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
istio-system    servicegraph                            ClusterIP      10.96.66.82      <none>        8088/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
istio-system    tracing                                 ClusterIP      10.104.57.157    <none>        80/TCP                                                                                                                    16h
istio-system    zipkin                                  ClusterIP      10.109.76.209    <none>        9411/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
kube-system     kube-dns                                ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                                                                                                             16h
vick-system     gateway                                 ClusterIP      10.101.191.90    <none>        8280/TCP,8243/TCP,9763/TCP,9443/TCP                                                                                       16h
vick-system     vick-observability-portal               ClusterIP      10.100.113.178   <none>        3000/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
vick-system     wso2apim-with-analytics-rdbms-service   ClusterIP      10.99.21.97      <none>        3306/TCP                                                                                                                  16h
vick-system     wso2sp-worker                           ClusterIP      10.96.175.235    <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9411/TCP,9443/TCP,9090/TCP,7611/TCP,7711/TCP,9611/TCP,9711/TCP,7443/TCP,9123/TCP                        16h
```

My /etc/hosts file:

```
pasan@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu
10.0.2.15   wso2-apim-gateway wso2-apim wso2sp-dashboard istio-ingress
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Based solely on the output of `get svc`, it looks like http://wso2-apim:31139 should work, but to be honest, I was expecting to see the address of your virtualbox machine in your question, since that is the address upon which the NodePort will be listening (it may very well be 10.0.2.15, I don't know)

Comment: Hi  @MatthewLDaniel How can I find this IP of virtual machine. I have enabled host-only network from virtualbox..

Comment: ssh into it through whatever means you provisioned it and run `ip addr`, although I don't know how you got this far in your experiment without already knowing its IP address

Comment: The problem I was having was my host-only network IP address not being recognized by the guest OS. I resolved this by adding the relevent entry in /etc/network/interfaces as described in the comment section of [this](https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/) article. Then I used that IP (192.168.X.X) as the IP in nginx-ingress service. After this I could access the URLs from my host.